# My Adapter for my ListView is giving me this error: UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView

Tags: android, android-adapterview

I am trying to figure out why, but I am not sure. I looked and looked and I'm positive that I typed everything in that I was suppose to. I will post my code below.

Adapter Class:

```
public class MyAgendaAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<Agenda> agendas = new ArrayList<Agenda>();

public MyAgendaAdapter() {
    agendas.add(new Agenda());
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return agendas.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return agendas.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) { 
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.agenda, parent, false);
    }

    Agenda agenda = agendas.get(position); //get the agenda from the ArrayList

    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.agenda_name);
    nameTextView.setText(agenda.getEvent());

    TextView timeTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.agenda_time);
    timeTextView.setText(agenda.getTime());

    TextView locationTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.agenda_location);
    locationTextView.setText(agenda.getLocation());



    return convertView;
     }

}
```

Main Activity class:

```
public class MainDisplayActivity extends Activity {
    MyAgendaAdapter agendaAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.agenda_list); 
    agendaAdapter = new MyAgendaAdapter();
    list.setAdapter(agendaAdapter);
    }

}
```

I omitted the imports. Assuming that my layouts and ID's are correct, does anyone know what the issue is?

Edit (Exact errors on the logcat):

```
05-27 17:29:54.839: W/dalvikvm(1065): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception(group=0x409c01f8)
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zeroe/com.zeroe.MainDisplayActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:471)
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:743)
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at com.zeroe.MainDisplayActivity.onCreate(MainDisplayActivity.java:21)
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
05-27 17:29:54.860: E/AndroidRuntime(1065):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

So after conversation edit `MyAgendaAdapter` class and edit it's `conctructor` like this:

```
public MyAgendaAdapter(Context c) {
    this.context = c;
    agendas.add(new Agenda());
}
```

So you will have:

```
public class MyAgendaAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Agenda> agendas = new ArrayList<Agenda>();

public MyAgendaAdapter() {
    agendas.add(new Agenda());
}
...
```

Then add this to your `getView` method

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.agenda, null);
    }
```

And then you will call like this:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.agenda_list); 
    agendaAdapter = new MyAgendaAdapter(this);
    list.setAdapter(agendaAdapter);
```

And tell me then.

---

So alternative way which inner class:

```
public class MainDisplayActivity extends Activity {
    MyAgendaAdapter agendaAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.agenda_list); 
    agendaAdapter = new MyAgendaAdapter();
    list.setAdapter(agendaAdapter);
    }

private class MyAgendaAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<Agenda> agendas = new ArrayList<Agenda>();

public MyAgendaAdapter() {
    agendas.add(new Agenda());
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return agendas.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return agendas.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) { 
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.agenda, null);
    }

    Agenda agenda = agendas.get(position); //get the agenda from the ArrayList

    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.agenda_name);
    nameTextView.setText(agenda.getEvent());

    TextView timeTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.agenda_time);
    timeTextView.setText(agenda.getTime());

    TextView locationTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.agenda_location);
    locationTextView.setText(agenda.getLocation());



    return convertView;
     }

}

}
```

Comment: convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.agenda, null);
This is not the correct way of working, inflating should always have a  container/parent, This will also resolve your exception. You should use inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay,container,false)